# How can I make VLC stream continuously?

Tags: wireless-networking, vlc-media-player, streaming, smb, osx-yosemite

I'am trying to watch a movie in VLC. The movie is in a local SMB share via wireless and I'm using a Mac 10.10.

When I start the movie, it starts downloading at 7MB/s for a few seconds (which is good) and then it starts to play.
The problem is while it's playing is not downloading at the same time (download stops), so in a couple minutes the playback stops(the buffer must have ended), then 10/15 seconds to download at 7MB/s and then it resumes again. Until the end of the movie I experience several stops, which is very unpleasant.

Is there anything I can do to play the video continuously?
(I could copy the entire video in one minute or so and then watch it, but that would defeat the purpose)

Comment: wire up instead.

Comment: I think it's not about being wireless or not. Because 7MB/s it fast enough. The problem is the download stops. Like VLC downloads 70MB and plays it, when it's over it downloads 70MB again.. (70MB or something)

Comment: it would still test whether it was the wifi or not. Yosemite & wifi seem not to be the best of friends.

Comment: ok, I will test it and comeback to share the results. Thanks

Comment: I changed your tagging, if you don't mind; I think Yosemite & wifi may be more relevant tags

Comment: So, I tried with cable... It's the same thing, only now it takes like 1 second to download the rest of the buffer... but it stops.

Comment: I think the problem is about VLC and/or SMB. Yosemite and wireless don't have anything to do with it. What I was expecting, is VLC to download the entire movie even when it's playing.

Comment: I do the same thing frequently, storage on Win, player on VLC Mac 10.9, but wired. No issues, even on very high res BD rips, 10GB movies etc. Might possibly be the movie file-type, but I've no evidence either way.

Comment: I tried with different players that played .mkv (XBMC, NicePlayer and MplayerX) and all of them kept downloading when the playback started. So I am assuming it's VLC fault or something.. (Also tried with .mp4, no difference). I'm now using XBMC, it's nice because it connects directly to the share. Thanks